# Start activity with new task(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) take too much time

Tags: android

I start new activity from application context with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
It work normal in case when there any launched activity from my app, but when there no activities, it take 2-3 sec. (between startActivity(intent) and onCreate()).
Is creating new task so heavy operation? 
Can i decrease this time?